# Receive notification at particular time from webservice

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my application i need one functionality say: Appointment. Appointment will be created from website.

Once it is created, at particular time(Say appointment time) webservice will be triggered and send

response.From android, i have to wait for that particular response and catch that response and i will

send to notification.the question is ..how do i find that webservice is sending response,and how do i

recieve that response whenever service sends response.

It will be more helpful if any1 provide me with clear answer...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called push notifications. 
Google provides this through c2md (deprecated) and the new, but nearly the same, GCM.

You can find a lot of info about this by searching those 2 terms.

Also I can recommend using UrbanAirship.com, as they simplify the process greatly and are free up until a great amount of notifications. 
They've got extensive documentation and examples on how to send and receive from both client as server.